# Magento 2.2.4 Payment module form field

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, magento2.2.4

I install this module in fresh magento 2 but i just see on frontend shipping address module should show credit card fields.

here is module link
https://github.com/ajzele/B05032-Foggyline_Paybox

please advice how to ad form fields in this module if its not define.

Comment: anyone please help